# How to initialize covariant variable?

Tags: scala, covariance

`class C [+T] {
  var v : T = _
}`

compiler error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value value_=

why? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot have a var of a covariant type.
A var amounts to having, among other things, a public `def v_=(newV: T)`, so it makes T appears as a routine argument, which is a contravariant position. So you must either

- renounce covariance and declare  C[T] rather than C[+T]
- make v a val

To be a little more verbose on the "why" part of your question, by making T is covariant parameter with +T, you states that you wants C[B] to a a subtype of C[A] if B is a subtype of A. This means you want to allows :

```
val cb: C[B] = new C[B]
val ca : C[A] = cb
```

To makes this sounds, the compiler restricts where T may appear in C. To make it short and with minor simplifications, v cannot appear as parameter of a routine (or as the type of a var). Otherwise, after you have initialized cb and ca as described above you coulddo

```
ca.v = new A
```

This would be allowed, as `ca` is supposed to be a `C[A]`, so its variable `v` is of type `A`. However, as C is covariant in T, `ca` may (and does in the example) reference a `C[B]` instance. Would this assignment be allowed, you could then do

```
val vInCb: B = cb.v
```

confident that this gives you a **B**. However, you just put an **A** there through the `ca` reference. This situation must be forbidden, and it is, by forbidding covariant type parameter T as the type of a var.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, I had written a third variant with private and removed it after tests, I had forgotten the [this]

Answer (score 11):

You can declare it as `private[this]`:

```
class C [+T] { private[this] var v : T = _ }
```

Any usage you try that this scope does not allow would be unsafe with a co-variant `T`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make it a `val`. A `var` always has a setter method where the type appears in contravariant position.